# React Routing is Not wokring

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am totally new in react. I am trying to use react router in my project.In webpack config file i change the historyApiFallback = true still couldn't figure out the routing problem. I am having "Cannot GET /header"  this error

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry:'./src/app.js',
    output:{
        path:path.join(__dirname,'public'),
        filename:'bundle.js'
    },
    module:{
        rules:[
            {
                test:/\.js$/,
                loader:'babel-loader',
                exclude:/node-modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true
      }
}
```

Comment: show your webpack.config.js

Comment: add in the post pls

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your devServer then you are missing it

```
devServer: {
            contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
            publicPath: '/',
            historyApiFallback: true
        }
```